# Swing Jcombobox

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jcombobox, itemlistener

what i m doing is, i am creating dynamic drop down lists (jcombobox). i m facing problem with the second combox. whenever i select a name from list1 the sec. list shows its names acc. to first list thats ok but when i again select a different name from list1 the list2 keep on showing the previous data and the new data...
i m using the function removeallitems() still i m not able to remove the previous data from list2

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
  if (e.getSource() == combo) {
    statename = (String)combo.getSelectedItem();
    try {
      ResultSet rs2 =s.executeQuery("select distinct district_name from district_master where state_code=(select state_code from state_master where state_name='"+statename+"') order by district_name ");
      while(rs2.next()) {  
        districtlist.add(rs2.getString(1));
      }
      list_district  = new String [districtlist.size()];
      districtlist.toArray(list_district);
    } catch(Exception f) {
      f.printStackTrace();
      System.out.println(f);
    }
    combo1.setEnabled(true);
    combo1.removeAllItems();
    for (int i = 0; i < list_district.length; i++) {
      combo1.removeItem(list_district[i]);
      combo1.addItem(list_district[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

i am giving only a part of my program where i am facing problem...

Comment: Next time, please provide us with formatted code...

Comment: Why do you copy your List to an array? You can loop directly on the list `for(String s: districtlist) {combo1.addItem(s);}`. Remove that removeItem inside your loop as it does not do anything. Next time you hit something like this, use a debugger.

Comment: Executing queries should not happen on the Event Dispatch Thread. Long running tasks should happen on a worker thread to ensure a responsive UI. Take a look at the [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) tutorial from the Oracle site for more details on the how and why

Answer (score 3):

You are not clearing out your districtlist everytime you run the query.  This means that every time you query you are adding to the lists items from the previous queries.

Try doing this instead.

```
districtlist.clear();
while(rs2.next())
{
    districtlist.add(rs2.getString(1));

}
```

Comment: No problem, I have to admit it was a little confusing with the similarly named variables.

Answer (score 1):

Right before your `while` loop, you should clear your list of items:

```
districtlist.clear();
while(rs2.next()){
  //...
}
```

Comment: you are clearing the wrong variable.  The variable you are pointing to is the array, the list he should be clearing is districtlist as per my answer.

Comment: @JonTaylor Oops, thanks for pointing this out, copied the wrong variable. U deserve a +1

Comment: @both I see districtlist.clear();, aaaaach not clear(), list_district  = new JList (List or whatever)